# Vertically centering two floating elements respective to each other

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I realise vertically centring is a topic which comes up often on here and other websites but I'm still new to HTML and even after reading up on this topic I'm still confused.

I've tried making a simple header element for a website which contains an h1 title and a nav ul for the navigation links. Here is the html:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
<head>
   <title>Sample website</title> 
   <link href="css/homepage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <header>
   <h1>Website Title Here</h1> 
    <ul>
    | <li><a href="#">Home</a></li> |
      <li><a href="./about/index.html">About me</a></li> |
      <li><a href="./contact/index.html">Contact me</a></li> |
      <li><a href="http://throughbenslens.co.uk/blog">My blog</a></li> |
      <li><a href="./portfolio/index.html">My portfolio</a></li> |
   </ul>
    </header>

    <hr class="hrstyle" style="clear:both;"/>

</body>
</html>
```

And the respective CSS:

```
header{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin:auto;
}

h1{
    font-family: Helvetica;
    float: left;
    padding:0;
}

ul{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;   
    padding:0;
}

li {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

.hrstyle{
    max-width:1000px;
}
```

I'm trying to get the h1 title and nav list to line centre align to one another vertically. Currently it looks like this...

[image: element aligment]

With the nav element appearing at the top of the header.

I've read numerous things but I'm hesitant to just blindly copy code from the internet without fully understanding it.

Comment: You should post a jsfiddle with the code so people can see a live example with just one click! I've gone ahead and done it for you already. http://jsfiddle.net/AnPkT/

Comment: Apologies, I have never came across jsfiddle before today, neat little tool! Thanks.

Comment: As a side-note: Always use CSS Reset at the beginning to override the browser default stylesheet. many of similar issues is caused by default styles of browsers. (Take a look at [Eric Meyer's CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset)).

Comment: I will look into that. If one should *always* use a CSS reset surely developers working on modern browsers should rethink their default browser CSS files?

Comment: Since different browsers have different behaviors, most web developers use CSS reset or Normalize as *a start point* to reset default styles of all browsers. It helps to make a cross-browser web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try `line-height`. Add this to your `ul` in your CSS

```
ul {
  ...
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

Tweak the number to your desire.

Here's a little tutorial for you on different vertical centering techniques. I'll keep adding to this. But it might illustrate for you how elements react to different styling.

[Codpen example on `padding` and `line-height`](http://cdpn.io/zpqAf)

Comment: Whilst this works in a way - i.e. I can shift the ul element down - it's a bit messy. It doesn't perfectly centre it, it's just guess work - is there not a way of centring the elements to one another perfectly?

Comment: Added a link to some examples I'm building for you.

Answer (score 0):

For your ul add this:

```
ul{
  ...
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  right:0px;
}
```

Position absolute allows you to control the position of the element from the sides. So push it a certain amount from the top and 0 from the right. This will produce what you described.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AnPkT/2/